Expected shortfall in discrete cases
Our professor gives us a definition in continuous cases:
$$
\operatorname{ES}(p)=\frac{1}{1-p}\int_p^1 \operatorname{VaR}(z)\mathrm{d}z 
$$
where our value at risk (VaR) is defined as
$$
\operatorname{VaR}(p)=-\inf \{x\mid F(x)=P(X\leqslant x)\geqslant 1-p\}
$$
But I don't think this works in discrete cases: If we switch the integral $\int$ to discrete sum $\sum$, then the ES becomes
$$
\operatorname{ES}(p)=\frac{1}{1-p}\sum_{p_i\geqslant p}\operatorname{VaR}(p_i)
$$
This is not the average but the sum. Should I times a coefficient $\dfrac{1}{\text{number of }i \text{ such that }p_i\geqslant p}$? Can anyone help?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall
The form you have works whether $X$ (the portfolio gain or loss) is continuous or discrete. Note that the integral we are doing is not with respect to a pdf/pmf, but with a probability.
$\text{VaR}(z)$ will be piecewise constant if $X$ is discrete, so it can be written as a discrete sum as you note, but that sum will have to have a term along the lines of  ($z_i - z_{i-1}$), which is the discrete analogue of $dz$.
